# How do I open a dialog as soon as an application is initialized?

Tags: .net, wpf, startup

I'm trying to open a modal dialog as soon as a WPF application has started (using `ShowDialog(this)`). I tried the following methods, both of which throw an InvalidOperationException, presumably because the window hasn't been initialized yet:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ShowMyDialogDammit();
}
```

and:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);
    ShowMyDialogDammit();
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler for the [`FrameworkElement.Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event (which occurs "when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction"), and then open your dialog from within the event handler.
For example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Adding the event handler
    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(IsLoaded);
}

private void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowMyDialogDammit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it from the Loaded event of your windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var w = new MainWindow();
w.ShowDialog();
```

You don't need the "ShowDialog" call inside the MainWindow class anywhere.

Comment: It's for showing a separate modal dialog as soon as the main window is opened.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood the question. Sorry.